# Call extended class function

Tags: c++, class, oop, function, derived

So i have a class called **Person**

```
class Person{

   private:

   public:
      Person();

}
```

and 1 more class called **Patient**

```
class Patient : public Person{

    private:
       string text_;
    public:
       Patient();
       void setSomething(string text){ text_ = text; }
}
```

now i have created an array of 5 People like

```
Person *ppl[5];
```

and added 5 Patients in each key of the array like

```
ppl[0] = new Patient();
ppl[1] = new Patient();
ppl[2] = new Patient();
ppl[3] = new Patient();
ppl[4] = new Patient();
```

now i want to call the **setSomething** function **from the Patient class** like this

```
ppl[0]->setSomething("test text");
```

but i keep getting the following error:

```
class Person has no member named setSomething
```

Comment: What is the question? The compiler is very clear about what is wrong. `Person` has no `setSomething` method, so you cannot call it on a `Person` or pointer to `Person`.

Comment: i have added that Patient extends Person so i thought it could work...

Comment: since all the elements of the array are new Patients would i be able to call a function from the Patient class?

Comment: @juanchopanza You are right, sorry!

Comment: @fxuser: The elements of the array are Patients, but as far as the compiler is concerned the guarantee is that they are Persons and nothing more: `Person *ppl[5]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of `Person*`. You can only call public methods of `Person` on elements of that array, even if they point to `Patient` objects. To be able to call `Patient` methods, you would first have to cast the `Person*` to a `Patient*`.

```
Person* person = new Patient;
person->setSomething("foo"); // ERROR!

Patient* patient = dynamic_cast<Patient*>(person);
if (patient)
{
  patient->setSomething("foo");
} else
{
  // Failed to cast. Pointee must not be a Patient
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know that the pointer points to a `Patient` object, so you have to explicitly tell the compiler that it is:

```
static_cast<Patient*>(ppl[0])->setSomething(...);
```

Either that, or make `setSomething` a `virtual` function in the base class.

A small note though: Using `static_cast` only works if you're certain that the pointer is a pointer to a `Patient` object. If there is a change it's not, then you have to use `dynamic_cast` instead, and check that the result is not `nullptr`.